# How to shorten this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

is there any way to shorten this query like using case when for example?

```
     SELECT ords_id
FROM orders o
JOIN stocks s ON o.ords_stks_id = s.stks_id
WHERE (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%901%'
       AND o.ords_stas_id = 90
       AND o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
       AND o.ords_id = orderid)
  OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%1001%'
      AND o.ords_stas_id = 100
      AND o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
      AND o.ords_id = orderid)
  OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%801%'
      AND o.ords_stas_id = 80
      AND o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
      AND o.ords_id = orderid)
  OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%231%'
      AND o.ords_stas_id = 23
      AND o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
      AND o.ords_id = orderid)
```

Comment: Find the common parts, e.g. `o.lsnr is not null` and `o.ords_id = orderid`, you only need them once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes your query literally - I assume that s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS will contain the order ID with '1' appended...

```
select ords_id
 from orders o
     join stocks s on o.ords_stks_id = s.stks_id
 where 1=1
 and o.lsnr is not null
 and o.ords_id = orderid
 and s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS LIKE '%'||o.ords_stas_id||'1%'
 and o.ords_stas_id IN (90,100,80,23)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you could avoid repeating `o.lsnr is not null and o.ords_id = orderid` for every condition.

```
SELECT ords_id
FROM orders o
JOIN stocks s ON o.ords_stks_id = s.stks_id
WHERE o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
  AND o.ords_id = orderid
  AND ( (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%901%'
         AND o.ords_stas_id = 90)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%1001%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 100)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%801%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 80)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%231%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 23) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed some duplication:

```
SELECT ords_id
FROM orders o
JOIN stocks s ON o.ords_stks_id = s.stks_id
WHERE o.lsnr IS NOT NULL
  AND o.ords_id = orderid
  AND ((s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%901%'
        AND o.ords_stas_id = 90)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%1001%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 100)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%801%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 80)
       OR (s.stks_print_btn_status LIKE '%231%'
           AND o.ords_stas_id = 23));
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?  Is this purely shortening the query? You could move the duplicated part of the WHERE out to something like this:

```
select ords_id
 from orders o join stocks s on o.ords_stks_id = s.stks_id
where 
(o.lsnr is not null and o.ords_id = orderid)
 AND 
(s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS like '%901%' and o.ords_stas_id = 90) or
(s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS like '%1001%' and o.ords_stas_id = 100) or
(s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS like '%801%' and o.ords_stas_id = 80) or
(s.STKS_PRINT_BTN_STATUS like '%231%' and o.ords_stas_id = 23);
```

While that removes some duplication, I expect you are actually trying to achieve something else?